# Unable to run uwsgi with upstart/supervisord

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, supervisord, upstart

I'm not able to run uwsgi with upstart/supervisord, I used `pyenv` to setup python with `virtualenv myenv`, `myenv` has `python3.4.3` and system's python pointing to `python2.7.6`. I changed pyenv global to 3.4.3.

Right now as `my_user`, `which python` => `/home/my_user/.pyenv/shims/python` and `python --version` => `Python 3.4.3`.

When I do with sudo, I get `sudo which python` => `/usr/bin/python` and `sudo python --version` => `Python 2.7.6`.

`/etc/init/uwsgi_servers.conf` has

```
description "uWSGI instance to serve authservice in production"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites/ --uid my_user --gid my_user
```

and `/etc/uwsgi/sites/uwsgi.ini` has

```
[uwsgi]
# variables
projectname = accounts
base =  /home/my_user/django/accounts/
for-readline = /home/my_user/conf/django/accounts/env_var
  env = %(_)
endfor =

# config
chdir =  /home/my_user/django/accounts/
master = True
processes = 5
protocol = uwsgi
env = in_accounts.settings.production
module = in_accounts.wsgi
socket = /tmp/uwsgi_%(projectname).sock
chmod-socket = 666
home = /home/my_user/.virtualenvs/accounts_production
logto = %(base)/logs/uwsgi.log
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/%(projectname).log
vacuum = True
pidfile = /tmp/%(projectname).pid
die-on-term = true
```

When I run `sudo service uwsgi_servers start`, I get error from log

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.11.2 (64bit) on [Tue Oct 13 09:32:18 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 12 October 2015 11:59:31
os: Linux-3.16.0-43-generic #58~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 22 10:21:20 UTC 2015
nodename: st-auths-web1
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/sites
writing pidfile to /tmp/accounts.pid
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /home/my_user/django/accounts/current
your processes number limit is 13731
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/uwsgi_accounts.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:01:27)  [GCC 4.8.2]
Set PythonHome to /home/my_user/.virtualenvs/accounts_production
ImportError: No module named site
VACUUM: pidfile removed.
VACUUM: unix socket /tmp/uwsgi_accounts.sock removed.
```

From log I can see that starting uwsgi using upstart try to use `python2.7.6` since I use `sudo` to run upstart service, but It should have used `python3.4.3`, this might be the reason why server isn't running. Though I use `uid` and `gid` I get the above error. I also tried `setuid` and `setgid`, but no luck.

NOTE: I can able to run uwsgi server successfully without `upstart` as `uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites/`. I tried use `supervisord`, but no use, getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you will have to tell wsgi which virtualenv to use that's with the -H option. If your virtualenv is in your home folder, upstart will not be able to access it. So move it to a readable place and try

```
uwsgi -H /usr/local/virtualenv
```

or something like that with the correct path to the virtualenv in your upstart file.

Comment: Setting `home = /home/my_user/.virtualenvs/accounts_production` in uwsgi.ini would be fine right? I have done that already. I also tried as `sudo uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites/ -uid my_user -gid my_user` without upstart and getting same error. This is the same command I used in upstart script.

Comment: If upstart running as your account should be ok. But when running without upstart did you use -H to set virtualenv path? Id you try install into virtualenv direct and run from there? (pip install uswsgi ?)

Comment: when running without upstart I didn't give -H explicitly and server running fine. you mean install uwsgi inside environment? if yes It is working fine inside environment.